# Jenkins - Git connection issue with PROXY?

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Im getting the following error when trying to run a maven project that connect to our Git location.  I have set the proxy in Jenkins config, but not sure what to do.

```
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository https://<MY_GIT_URL>
> git.exe init C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\testMaven # 
timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://<MY_GIT_URL>
> git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
Setting http proxy: <MY_PROXY_URL>.com:7070
> git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://<MY_GIT_URL> 
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git.exe fetch --tags --progress 
https://<MY_GIT_URL> +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status 
code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: unable to access 'https:<MY_GIT_URL>': Failed to connect to 
<MY_PROXY_URL>.com port 7070: Timed out

Timed out

at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2016)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1735)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:72)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:420)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:629)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1146)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1186)
at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:504)
at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1208)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1815)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
```

Comment: Where exactly did you configure your proxy? I think if you use git, you'd need to configure the proxy for git, for the jenkins user

Comment: The proxy is configured under the Advanced section of the "Git Plugins" page.